# failed to send post data from phonegap app to RESTful lib

Tags: php, ajax, rest, codeigniter-2, cordova-3

I'm trying to send data from a phonegap mobile app to my server using `$.ajax` method
I use this code :

```js
var form_data = {parm: 1, token: "2fa7e7e5e76005ffd8bfa5082da9f2f9"};
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/index.php/register_devices/register/format/json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    //dataType:"jsonp",
    success: function(data){
            alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert('request failed: '+ errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
```

I also put this line in my config.xml file :

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And in the server side I use `codeigniter` framework with `RESTful` library  like this code :

```php
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
class Register_devices extends REST_Controller  {
    public function register_post()
    {
        $parm = $this->input->post('parm');
        $token = $this->input->post('token');
        echo $token;
    }
}
```

when I use `GET` method it works successfully but the problem is when I use `POST` method I receive :

> "internal server error"

.. Any solve ?

Comment: Turn all error reporting on to actually see the error. Probably some in CI config too.

Comment: How can I do that ? I'm debugging with alert statement in the client

Comment: The error reporting is in PHP. Look it up. If you enable it, it will say something useful instead of "internal server error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because this config option :

`$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`

I just put it `FALSE` and it works prefect .